# CSS padding/margins not working as expected

Tags: css, padding, margins

I want a button similar to this:

[image]

But this is mine:

[image]

Here's the CSS:

```
.cubutton {
border-radius: 99999px; /* Round button corners here with border-radius */
    background-color: #44ace8;
color: #fff;
cursor: pointer;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
font-size: 2.0rem; 
font-weight: 700;
letter-spacing: 1px;
padding: 20px 40px 20px 40px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75); /* Adds drop shadow to button. */
-moz-box-shadow:    4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
box-shadow:         4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition:    all 0.1s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition:     all 0.1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition:      all 0.1s ease-in-out;
transition:         all 0.1s ease-in-out; 
}
```

For the life of me, I cannot figure out why the padding and margins don't show. I'm not a coding expert by any means, so I could easily be overlooking something obvious.

Here's the html:

```
<a data-sumome-listbuilder-id="11553d26-bca5-4975-91e8-e5fdf2937bf8"
 class="cubutton" data-sumome-trigger="true" 
 href="javascript:void(0);">Take this post with you. Get the PDF version. 100% free. Click here.</a>
```

Comment: Those paddings look right for 20 and 40px respectively if the font size is 20px. Try increasing it? Or do you want the button to be narrower?

Comment: What is the HTML?

Comment: Updated my answer based on the new HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually works. All you have to do is to adjust the background color and height of your div:

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ohjg39f9/)

```
.cubutton {
border-radius: 99999px; /* Round button corners here with border-radius */
    background-color: #83d55c;
    min-height: 90px;
color: #fff;
cursor: pointer;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
font-size: 98px;
font-weight: 700;
letter-spacing: 1px;
padding: 20px 40px 20px 40px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75); /* Adds drop shadow to button. */
-moz-box-shadow:    4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
box-shadow:         4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition:    all 0.1s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition:     all 0.1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition:      all 0.1s ease-in-out;
transition:         all 0.1s ease-in-out; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set a width on the element (presuming it's a block level element), otherwise it will always span the width of its parent. In order to avoid having the padding adjust the overall width, you'll want to explicitly set the [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).

[Working JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/j5t87ztc/3/).

```
.cubutton {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 60px 100px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 50%;
}
```

**Edit:** Updated Fiddle and CSS to match updated question (using an `<a>` tag).

Comment: Thanks everyone. I was a bit confused by all the suggestions at first. But now, I got it working and it looks awesome!

Comment: Glad to hear it. Don't forget to accept whichever answer did the track as the 'accepted answer'.

Answer (score 0):

To get the problem I needed your html since the problem is there.

You can't get the same look because you are using an anchor as a button and it doesn't let you make line breaks nor change the width. So in short you have to much text to be using an anchor as a button.

[This pen](https://codepen.io/svinkle/pen/FHGBh) makes it work, but with only two word.

Here's an [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ohjg39f9/1/) where I simply change the markup to this:

```
<button data-sumome-listbuilder-id="11553d26-bca5-4975-91e8-e5fdf2937bf8" class="cubutton" data-sumome-trigger="true" href="javascript:void(0);">
Take this post with you. <br/> Get the PDF version.<br/> 100% free. Click here.</button>
```

and it looks exactly how you want it.

---

EDIT: 
As will pointed out you can actually keep it as anchor if adding 'display: block' to it. Tho, in that case, you would also need to give it a width and make the text-align in the center.

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ohjg39f9/2/)

Comment: @Will I can't comment on other people's post yet, but I made an edit of their question with the html. But until it's peered reviewed you can get it in this fiddle. It's the <a>. Placing it in your fiddle didn't solve the problem, it's really the tag.